# ValueError: when sending a str, it must be a hex string. Got: "'0x6e...32'"

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, ethereum, web3py

web3s.py

```
from web3 import Web3
import json

url = 'https://kovan.infura.io/v3/NODE'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(url))

abi = json.loads('[{"ABI"}]')
Raw_ADDRESS = MY_ADDRESS 
address = web3.toChecksumAddress(Raw_ADDRESS) 
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address,abi=ABI)
default_GasPrice = '5'

def firstMethod(Address1,publicKey,privateKey,GasPrice = default_GasPrice ) :

    Address1 = web3.toChecksumAddress(Address1) 
    publicKey = web3.toChecksumAddress(publicKey) 

    if web3.isConnected()  :    
        nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(publicKey) 
        transaction = contract.functions.firstMethod(Address1).buildTransaction({
            'from': publicKey , 
            'gasPrice': web3.toWei(GasPrice, 'gwei'),
            'nonce': nonce ,
            })
...
```

when i define address1 and address2 in web3s.py , codes work well but when i call firstMethod() in another file (from Django-Rest View) after import and pass **same** arguments , it returns :

```
File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eth_utils/conversions.py", line 159, in hexstr_if_str
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: when sending a str, it must be a hex string. Got: "'0x6e...32'"
```

as shown , i use infura not etherscan

where is the problem ?

Comment: Not having any knowledge of the etherium libraries you're using, but just going by the error message itself: That looks like the `'`s aren't expected, and maybe also not the `0x`. Make sure you send the literal string, not the `repr()` of it, to avoid the extra quotes.

Comment: See https://github.com/ethereum/eth-utils/blob/9d0ba061c55161849ae31a99326329534e0ed1b2/eth_utils/conversions.py#L144-L165 -- the `0x` is fine (ignored if present), so it's just the quotes that are causing you trouble. I don't see enough detail in the code to know where they're coming from -- maybe it's one of the values you redacted? A [mre] _does_ need to be runnable without changes by others to see a problem (perhaps use a testnet address so you can provide usable constants)?